# Plotly.js with WebGL over the vuejs app not working (WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid & drawArraysInstancedANGLE)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, plotly, webgl

Plotly version that I am using 2.14.0 (latest)
VueJs version 3.2.37 (latest)

Trying to plot with the type "scattergl". But the Chrome/Edge browsers complains with the error messages

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArraysInstancedANGLE: no valid shader program in use
```

And the plot is not fully rendered except the dots like shown below

[image]

I am trying to plot this inside a vue component.
As a newbie to WebGL, I am finding it difficult to debug this problem.

**Another clue:** When I take the plot Data out of vue application and locally try to plot using a plain html, then the plotting works with WebGL. The plot from my local html file looks like

[image]

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, because there are 2 versions of plotly.js namely

1. plotly.js
2. plotly.js-dist

Once I changed my vue project to use the **plotly.js-dist**, the error is gone and my vue component is able to plot.